# Ionic 2 Error of X page is part of the declarations of 2 modules

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, angular-module

I had gone through SO questions over here. But I am Unable to get What this error is trying to suggest. Please Help me out for this. [image: Error]

Lastly, HIGHER MODULE Means which module. As I am new to this That is why Not getting this correctly.

Mycode:

app.module.ts

```
   @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    UsersPage,
    ReposPage,
    OrganisationsPage,
    UserDetailsPage,
    LoginPage

  ],
  imports: [

    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),

  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    LoginPage,
    UsersPage,
    ReposPage,
    OrganisationsPage,
    UserDetailsPage,


  ],
```

Login.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule,IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginPage } from './login';
//import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(LoginPage),
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    LoginPage
  ],
  exports: [
    LoginPage
  ]
})
export class LoginPageModule {}
```

**UPDATED CODE AS PER YOUR COMMENT**

app.module.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController, LoadingController, Loading, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AuthService } from '../../providers/auth-service';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {
  loading: Loading;
  registerCredentials = { email: '', password: '' };

  constructor(private nav: NavController, private auth: AuthService, private alertCtrl: AlertController, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController) { }

  public createAccount() {
    this.nav.push('RegisterPage');
  }

  public login() {
    this.showLoading()
    this.auth.login(this.registerCredentials).subscribe(allowed => {
      console.log(allowed)
      if (allowed) {        
        this.nav.setRoot('HomePage');
      } else {
        this.showError("Access Denied");
      }
    },
      error => {
        this.showError(error);
      });
  }

  showLoading() {
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Please wait...',
      dismissOnPageChange: true
    });
    this.loading.present();
  }

  showError(text) {
    this.loading.dismiss();

    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Fail',
      subTitle: text,
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present(prompt);
  }
}
```

**login.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule,IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginPage } from './login';
//import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(LoginPage),
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    LoginPage
  ],
  exports: [
    LoginPage
  ]
})
export class LoginPageModule {}
```

**login.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController, LoadingController, Loading, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AuthService } from '../../providers/auth-service';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {
  loading: Loading;
  registerCredentials = { email: '', password: '' };

  constructor(private nav: NavController, private auth: AuthService, private alertCtrl: AlertController, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController) { }

  public createAccount() {
    this.nav.push('RegisterPage');
  }

  public login() {
    this.showLoading()
    this.auth.login(this.registerCredentials).subscribe(allowed => {
      console.log(allowed)
      if (allowed) {        
        this.nav.setRoot('HomePage');
      } else {
        this.showError("Access Denied");
      }
    },
      error => {
        this.showError(error);
      });
  }

  showLoading() {
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Please wait...',
      dismissOnPageChange: true
    });
    this.loading.present();
  }

  showError(text) {
    this.loading.dismiss();

    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Fail',
      subTitle: text,
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present(prompt);
  }
}
```

Comment: Any correct answer for this.. I am facing same issue

Answer (score 5):

I assume you're using the Lazy Load feature of Ionic. What that error means, is that you're including the `LoginPage` in the `declarations` array of the `NgModule` both in the `AppModule` (`app.module.ts` file) and the `LoginPageModule`.

In order to fix it, remove the `LoginPage` declaration of the `AppModule`, and if you need to use the `LoginPage` somewhere in the app (for instance, if you want to push that page), use the name but as a string, like this:

```
// Somewhere in your app
this.navCtrl.push('LoginPage'); // <- The name of the page is used as a string
```

Since the name of the page is now a string, you **won't need to import the `LoginPage` anymore**

```
// import { LoginPage } from '/path/to/login-page.ts'; <- You won't need to do this anymore
```

---

**UPDATE**

Just like you can see in the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/) (thanks @suraj), please check that you're creating the module of the `LoginPage` like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(MyPage)
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    MyPage
  ]
})
export class MyPageModule {}
```

And also check that you're adding the `@IonicPage()` decorator to the page:

```
// Ionic
import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({...})
export class MyPage {}
```

Comment: Now I got error as :): Error: No component factory found for LoginPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents? Error: No component factory found for LoginPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents? at noComponentFactoryError. @sebaferreras

Comment: Or if I m defining it in entry component then it giving this error: Component LoginPage is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module. ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Component LoginPage is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

Comment: I've updated the answer, could you please check your code to see if you see any difference?

Comment: I had done exactly what you have updated.Yet error is  `id you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents? Error: No component factory found for LoginPage`  Only diff is `import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';` this instead of `import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';`

Comment: but in the `LoginPage` you should use the `@IonicPage()` decorator, so the import should be `import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';`

Comment: I had done exactly what you have said: 1.Removed the LoginPage from `app.module.ts` then included `@IonicPage()` decorator with `import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';` Now what happening is  ionicApp page throwing blank Page, But If add `LoginPage` to app.module.ts then its works but @ end same issue which I posted in image above. Updated the question with code

Comment: No, the code you've posted is wrong! The `@IonicPage()` decorator **should not be on top of the `@NgModule({...})`**. Should be on top of the `LoginPage` component. And remove every line of `LoginPage` from the `app.module.ts` (including the import statement). **Please take a look carefully at the update of my answer, because your code does not do the same I've posted**

Comment: Please see updated code. Error thrown : Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for LoginPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents? @sebaferreras

Comment: Do you have a github repo I can take a look? That way I can work directly on that repo and take a look at the issue