# Ionic 3 Error of LoginPage is part of the declarations of 2 modules

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I am new to ionic 3, I am navigating one page to another, for navigation Im using this.navCtrl.setRoot(RegistrationPage) and after app launch Im setting the root page as a login page. and so on.. When I am into the some dashbaord page and in menu items I have logout button, on click of logout im again setting rootpage a loginpage but here im getting error.

[image]

Image copied from [Ionic 2 Error of X page is part of the declarations of 2 modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630233/ionic-2-error-of-x-page-is-part-of-the-declarations-of-2-modules)

Same issue im facing but that answer didnt help me

app.mudule.js

```
//Pages
      import { MyApp } from './app.component';
      import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
      import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
      import { UserdashboardPage } from 
      '../pages/userdashboard/userdashboard';
      import { ManagerdashboardPage } from 
     '../pages/managerdashboard/managerdashboard'; 
     import { RegistrationPage } from '../pages/registration/registration';
      import { ModalViewPage } from '../pages/modal-view/modal-view';
      import { ReRegistrationPage } from '../pages/re-registration/re-
     registration';


    @NgModule({
    declarations: [
    MyApp,
   HomePage,
   LoginPage,
  UserdashboardPage,
  ManagerdashboardPage,
  RegistrationPage,
  ModalViewPage,
  ReRegistrationPage

],
 imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
  TranslateModule.forRoot({
  loader: {
      provide: TranslateLoader,
      useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
      deps: [HttpClient]
  }
})   
],
bootstrap: [IonicApp],
entryComponents: [
MyApp,
HomePage,
LoginPage,
UserdashboardPage,
ManagerdashboardPage,
RegistrationPage,
ModalViewPage,
ReRegistrationPage

],
providers: [
StatusBar,
SplashScreen,
{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
HttpModule,
HttpClientModule,
LoginServiceProvider,
Device,
AlertServiceProvider,
LanguageConversionProvider,
FCM,
Network,
NetworkconnectivityProvider,
Constants
]
 })
  export class AppModule {}

  export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
 /  /return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
 }
```

app.component.js

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
   import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
       import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
    import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
  import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device';
 import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm';

     import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
    import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
     import { UserdashboardPage } from 
   '../pages/userdashboard/userdashboard';
  import { RegistrationPage } from '../pages/registration/registration';
    import { ReRegistrationPage } from '../pages/re-registration/re-
 registration';


   import { NetworkconnectivityProvider } from 
    '../providers/networkconnectivity/networkconnectivity';
     import { AlertServiceProvider } from '../providers/alert-service/alert-
      service';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
    import { LanguageConversionProvider } from '../providers/language-
   conversion/language-conversion';

  export interface MenuItem {
  title: string;
  component: any;
 icon: string;
}

  @Component({
   templateUrl: 'app.html'
 })
export class MyApp {
    public rootPage;
     pages: any = [];
     appMenuItems: Array<MenuItem>;
   @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
constructor(platform: Platform ...) {

this.appMenuItems = [
  { title: 'Home', component: UserdashboardPage, icon: 'home' },
  { title: 'Device Registration', component: ReRegistrationPage, icon: 'people' },
  { title: 'About', component: '', icon: 'information-circle' },
  { title: 'Logout', component: 'LoginPage', icon: 'log-out' },
];

platform.ready().then(() => {
  console.log("Device ready event fired platform this.device.platform -- " + this.device.platform);
  statusBar.styleDefault();
  splashScreen.hide();
  translateService.setDefaultLang('en');
  translateService.use('en');


  //FCM registration and on receive notifications code
  if (this.networkCheck.isOnline) {
    fcm.subscribeToTopic('marketing');
    fcm.getToken().then(token => {
      //backend.registerToken(token);
      console.log("FCM token -- " + token);
      if (token == '' || token == null || token == undefined) {
        this.showAlertService.showAlert(this.langConvService.convertLang('Err_Invalid_Access_Title'), this.langConvService.convertLang('Err_Token_Txt'), this.langConvService.convertLang('Ok'));
        return false;
      }
      this.storage.set('fcmToken', token);
    }).catch(error => {
      this.showAlertService.showAlert(this.langConvService.convertLang('Err_Invalid_Access_Title'), this.langConvService.convertLang('Err_Token_Txt'), this.langConvService.convertLang('Ok'));
      console.log("getToken() FCM token -- ", JSON.stringify(error))
    });
  } else {
    console.log("Device is offline")
    this.showAlertService.showAlert(this.langConvService.convertLang('Err_Nw_Title'), this.langConvService.convertLang('Err_Nw_Txt'), this.langConvService.convertLang('Ok'));
  }


  fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
    if (data.wasTapped) {
      console.log("Received in background");
    } else {
      console.log("Received in foreground");
    };
  })


  fcm.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(token => {
    //backend.registerToken(token);
    console.log("onTokenRefresh() tokentokenv -- " + token);
  })

  //judging login or home page
  this.storage.get('loginStatus').then(loggedIn => {
    console.log("loggedIn -- ", loggedIn)
    this.rootPage = loggedIn ? UserdashboardPage : LoginPage;
  });

});
```

}

```
 openPage(page, event) {
  // Reset the content nav to have just this page
  // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario

  if(page.component == "LoginPage"){
  console.log("Logout button clicked");  
  // this.nav.pop();
  // this.nav.pop();
  this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  this.storage.clear(); 
}else{
  this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
}
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

}
}

Login.module.ts

```
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
  import { LoginPage } from './login';

 @NgModule({
  declarations: [
  LoginPage,
  ],
  imports: [
  IonicPageModule.forChild(LoginPage),
],
 })
 export class LoginPageModule {}
```

Comment: Is there a LoginPageModule? are you using lazy loading? also does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44630458/4826457) not fix it?

Comment: @SurajRao Please check, I have updated question

Comment: did you try that answer? remove the imports and the page form entryComponents,declarations from app.module.ts and also from app.component .. use strings when you are pushing pages.

Comment: @SurajRao Yes tried.. but not working.. its saying vendor.js:1703 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for LoginPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
Error: No component factory found for LoginPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Comment: did you remove the import from app.component.ts?

Comment: @SurajRao  Ya I have removed and getting the above error..

Comment: use string here too `this.rootPage = loggedIn ? UserdashboardPage : LoginPage;`

Comment: @SurajRao  got it working .. thank you.. Please add the answer.. I will accept.. because prevous answer was not accepted so I got confuse about that answer.. thats what i have asked seperate question.. Thank you

Comment: that is a different issue.. So it is going to login page now.. You will have to debug further

Comment: I had a problem with HomePage a long time ago because a Plugin had an example inside node_modules with the same name.